# How to avoid spacing when hover on the horizontal submenu?

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

I 'm working with Bones Theme on wordpress CMS and I'm trying to change the submenu orientation.

That's what happens:

[image: Problem when hover on this menu]

That's the HTML structure:

```
<nav role="navigation">
<ul id="menu-menu" class="nav top-nav clearfix">
    <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43">
            <a href="http://www.blablabla.com/blabla/">MENU-ITEM-1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://www.blablabla.com/blablabla/">submenu-item-1.1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="http://www.blablabla.com/blablabla/">submenu-item-1.2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="http://www.blablabla.com/blablabla">submenu-item-1.3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45"><a href="http://www.blablabla.com/blablabla/">submenu-item-1.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44">
        <a href="http://www.blablabla.com/blablabla/">MENU-ITEM-2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And thet's the CSS (I didn't write it, it's bones css code):

```
nav{
display: block;
}

.nav li {
float: left;
position: relative;
}

.nav li ul.sub-menu{
float: left;
display: none;
width: 100%;
padding: 3px 0px;
}

.nav li ul.sub-menu li a,
.nav li ul.children li a {
padding-left: 10px;
border-right: 0;
display: block;
width: 180px;
}

.nav li ul.sub-menu li:last-child a,
.nav li ul.children li:last-child a {
border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
top: auto;
display: block;
}
```

How can I avoid the problem of the first image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your submenu css to this:

```
.nav li ul.sub-menu{
float: left;
display: none;
width: 100%;
padding: 3px 0px;
margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: I did what you write but it didn't work, so i added some css code that maybe help you to understand what happens.

Comment: @dan please can you make a fiddle that I can edit to find the answer

Comment: thank you. The only differences is that i would have the submenu's item horizontally.

Comment: Just saying you need to get used to fiddles as they are used a lot in this site and people will take the mick because you don't know

Comment: yes, thank you. I'm trying to figure out how to correct this code, but unfortunately it's still not working

Comment: [Use this to help you make the children horizontal](http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/css-dropdown-menu/horizontal.html)